# ZipResourceFile getInputStream slow

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream, bitmapfactory, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to get assets from obb file using this lines:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile( aContext, 1, 0 );
InputStream is = expansionFile.getInputStream( aFileName );
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is, outPadding, aOptions );
is.close();
```

Those lines works to get the .png file but it is very slow compared with getting the .png directly from Assets directory.

Anyone has an idea or solution for this?

I have found the answer to my question.

This line makes the execution slow:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile( aContext, 1, 0 );
```

It was executed so many times before.

Comment: do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Yes..  It was slow because that codes was executed so often. getAPKExpansionZipFile is working fine.

Comment: so the solution is to cache expansionFile in class field or static field... do not run it everytime you are reading file

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my question.

This line makes the execution slow:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile( aContext, 1, 0 );
```

It was executed so many times before. After I removed that line from being called to often then everything works as expected.